# ModelState Validation Culture on HttpPost

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Does anyone know if you can control the culture of the ModelState Object, im facing a problem in my multilingual application where the language is based on which subdomain from which you visit the site ex:

> italia.domain.com - "Changes the culture to Italian"
>
> german.domain.com - "Changes the culture to German"

The issue is that the language on the ModelState object when submitting a form seems to be controlled by the Clients browser and not the current threads culture.

So im searching for a solution where i can modify this behavior or override it so that the language on my italian subdomain always is italian and not the language of the clients browser.

EDIT

**I already made the part where i change language based on subdomain:**

```
var HttpHost = HttpContext.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"];
var _hostname = (HttpHost.Split(':').Length > 1) ? HttpHost.Substring(0, HttpHost.IndexOf(':')) : HttpHost;

var allowedHostnames = "italiansubdomain.domain.com|it,frenchsubdomain.domain.com|fr,germansubdomain.domain.com|de,englishsubdomain.domain.com|en".Split(',');
foreach (var hostname in allowedHostnames)
{
    if (hostname.StartsWith(_hostname.ToLower()))
    {
        var lang = hostname.Split('|').Last();
        if (lang == "en") lang = "uk";
        // Updates the cultures for the dynamic language
        var ci = new CultureInfo(lang);
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
    }
}
```

So my problem is that when i use Modelstate validation like this:

```
public class Email {
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "validation_required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Master)), StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessageResourceName = "validation_string_length_2_50", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Master))]
    public string SenderName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "validation_required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Master)), Email(ErrorMessageResourceName = "validation_email_invalid", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Master))]
    public string SenderEmail { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "validation_required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Master)), StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessageResourceName = "validation_string_length_2_50", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Master))]
    public string ReceiverName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "validation_required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Master)), Email(ErrorMessageResourceName = "validation_email_invalid", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Master))]
    public string ReceiverEmail { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

And the check for modelstate validation part:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
  var keys = ModelState.Keys.ToList();
  var values = ModelState.Values.ToList();

  for (var i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
  {
      var value = values[i];
      if (value.Errors.Count > 0)
      { 
          response.AddError(keys[i], value.Errors[0].ErrorMessage);
      }
  }
}
```

When i then access the Errors through a Ajax Response result or just by debugging im receiving the error messages based on the browsers language setting, this is where i want to change it to be the language that is currently active instead.

EDIT

Thanks in advance, bsthomsen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by moving the code where the culture is being changed from Controller.OnActionExecuting to Controller.ExecuteCore

Comment: worked perfectly, thank you. I find it strange info on this issue seems so scarce. For most people this seems to work fine with just setting the UICulture, I wonder what's making it behave differently...

Comment: Well the explanation is rather simple, since Controller.OnActionExecution is when the controller is executed and is happening after the modelbinding which takes place before the controllers are executed.

Comment: In asp.net mvc 4 I suggest to override Initialize method from Controller class and there use localization code

Answer (score 0):

This libk should help [How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx)

add a globalization section to the Web.config file

```
<globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es-MX" />
```

or programmaticaly, override the `InitializeCulture` method for the page (WebForms)

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{

        UICulture = selectedLanguage ;
        Culture = selectedLanguage ;

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
            CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new 
            CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);

    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

or look at this question [Set Culture in an ASP.Net MVC app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560796/set-culture-in-an-asp-net-mvc-app)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i already made the part where it changes based on subdomain.. But somehow the ModelState messages doesnt change according to the threads culture, but according to the HttpPosted information..

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on a situation which was not exactly same but was similar. You should be able to set the UICulture of current thread to a specific language and things should work you expect it to. So, identify which subdomain the request is to and set the culture accordingly.  See more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i already made the part where it changes based on subdomain.. But somehow the ModelState messages doesnt change according to the threads culture, but according to the HttpPosted information..

Answer (score 0):

You can easily override the culture for each request in `Global.asax.cs`

In your case you could check the incoming URL and set the culture accordingly.

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Create culture info object 
     CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en");

     if(Request.Url.Host.Equals("italia.domain.com",
                                    StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
     {
          ci = new CultureInfo("it");
     }

     System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
     System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
                                      CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i already made the part where it changes based on subdomain.. But somehow the ModelState messages doesnt change according to the threads culture, but according to the HttpPosted information..