# When is the DefaultModelBinder invoked within the ASP.NET Pipeline?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, defaultmodelbinder, modelbinder

I want to know when the `DefaultModelBinder` is invoked within the ASP.NET Pipeline?

**Background:** I want to find an approriate place where I can set the cultures of the current thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if this [stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445278/change-culture-before-modelbinder-is-used) helps you.

Abstract from the answers above -
There are multiple events which execute before model binding in asp.net mvc, where you can set the culture for current request.

1. Application Request events like - "PreRequestHandlerExecute".
2. Extend the Controller base class and override the 'OnActionExecuting'
3. Create altogether new HttpModule.

Comment: Thanks! This also solved my problem that Data-annotated errors were not translated (because I did set the Culture in a filter).