# Pre-Append Route if not available

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

We have implemented a localized version of an ASP.NET MVC website which has a URL structure as following:

> url://{language}-{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}

In this way we can generate URLs by language which are properly crawled by Google bot:

1. http://localhost/en-US/Home
2. http://localhost/fr-FR/Home

The translation is achieved in two places. First we modified the default route of MVC with this one:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{language}-{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Home", 
        action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional,
        language = "en",
        culture = "US"
    }
);
```

Then we have created an action filter which switch to the current language available in the URL and if not available to the default one:

```
   public class LocalizationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {

            string language = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["language"] ?? "en";
            string culture = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["culture"] ?? "US";

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(string.Format("{0}-{1}", language, culture));
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(string.Format("{0}-{1}", language, culture));

        }
    }
}
```

The problem occurs if a user enter http://localhost/Whatever. ASP.NET MVC returns "Route not found". How can I pass a default parameter for the language if the user forgets to pass one? I though that by setting the default value into route config would be enough, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need another route to handle the case where there is no first segment.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default-Localized",
    url: "{language}-{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Home", 
        action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new
    {
        language = "en",
        culture = "US",
        controller = "Home", 
        action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

Matching the URL pattern and building the route values collection (based on defaults or the placeholders that can override them) are 2 different steps that are handled by the `Route` class. Populating route values doesn't happen unless the URL pattern matches first.

Do note that if you use an action filter to set the locale of the current thread that [localization won't be available inside of the model binder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445278/change-culture-before-modelbinder-is-used). A way around that is to use an `IAuthorizationFilter` instead of `ActionFilterAttribute`.

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class LocalizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var values = filterContext.RouteData.Values;

        string language = (string)values["language"] ?? "en";
        string culture = (string)values["culture"] ?? "US";

        CultureInfo ci= CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(string.Format("{0}-{1}", language, culture));

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
    }
}
```

And then add it as a global filter.

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new LocalizationFilter());
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```