# How to change site language using Resources and CultureInfo in ASP .NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have several resource files for each language I want to support, named like below:

```
NavigationMenu.en-US.resx
NavigationMenu.ru-RU.resx
NavigationMenu.uk-UA.resx
```

Files are located in `MySolution/Resources/NavigationMenu` folder.

I have action which sets `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` like below

```
public ActionResult SetLanguage(string lang)
{
    try
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang);
        return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

`lang` parameter values are `uk-UA`, `ru-RU` or `en-US` depending on what link in my view was clicked. Also I have web config globalization defined section:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="ru-RU" uiCulture="ru-RU" />
```

When my application starts I have Russian language as expected but when I try to change my language with `SetLanguage` action to English I get no language changes in my views. `NavigationMenu.SomeProperty` is still Russian. What am I missing?

Comment: This is a better answer in my opinion:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560796/set-culture-in-an-asp-net-mvc-app/1561583#1561583

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are updating the culture for the current thread only.

Most sites support localization by including this as part of their URL (in all pages). And with MVC, you can implement this approach by processing the culture using an action filter. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1561583/213902) has a good solution for this.

Aside from this, you would need to implement this by either persisting the culture to the session or a cookie, and then updating the thread's culture on every request, again by implementing an action filter, or during an application event that contains the request context, such as AquireRequestState.

Answer (score 4):

Persist your language in e.g cookie in your `SetLanguage()` and then in the `BaseController` or `ActionFilter` (recommended) get the values from cookie and the update the threads accordingly.
if this doesn't make any sense, take a look at the following nice articles;
**CodeProject** : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526827/MVC-Basic-Site-Step-1-Multilingual-Site-Skeleton
**And this One** :http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx
e.g;

```
// Save culture in a cookie
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
        if (cookie != null)
            cookie.Value = culture;   // update cookie value
        else
        {

            cookie = new HttpCookie("_culture");
            cookie.HttpOnly = false; // Not accessible by JS.
            cookie.Value = culture;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        }
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Comment: This is not best practice from an SEO perspective. See https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en. "Keep the content for each language on separate URLs. Don’t use cookies to show translated versions of the page. Consider cross-linking each language version of a page. That way, a French user who lands on the German version of your page can get to the right language version with a single click."

Comment: @JonRea agree but this is a quick and dirty way. And yes sometimes you don't need SEO such as the Administration area of application or a private locally deployed app.