# Decimal model binder not working with globalization

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm posting some data from the client to the server like this

```
$.post(url, myData)
   .done(function (data) {
   });
```

here's the controller's action

```
public class MyModel
{
   decimal Precision { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostInfo(MyModel postBack)
{
}
```

when I use the English culture *PostInfo* works as expected however when I change the culture to Spanish and *Precision* = 1,2 then I get the following error

> The value 1,2 is not valid for Precision

Can someone please tell me why the default model binder is failing to parse 1,2 when the *CurrentCulture* is Spanish?

I change the culture in *_Layout.cshtml*. It's for testing purpose only.

```
@{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es", "ES");
}
```

Comment: "When I change the culture to Spanish" - can you share where and how you are doing this?

Comment: @pep I've edited the question to show how I change the culture

Comment: Ah, that won't work. View rendering happens after the controller is invoked. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560796/set-culture-in-an-asp-net-mvc-app for several methods of setting the current culture. I suggest this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/6788690/1558122.

Answer (score 0):

the last time i checked, the default model binder doesn't handle internationalization formats. you would have to roll you own.

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        var modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;
        try
        {
            //Check if this is a nullable decimal and a null or empty string has been passed
            var isNullableAndNull = (bindingContext.ModelMetadata.IsNullableValueType &&
                                      string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueResult.AttemptedValue));

            //If not nullable and null then we should try and parse the decimal
            if (!isNullableAndNull)
            {
                actualValue = decimal.Parse(valueResult.AttemptedValue, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            modelState.Errors.Add(e);
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: according to this blog https://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization it does

Comment: That article says the exact opposite and  only mentions dates.  He says British date formats aren't natively supported and even gives an example of how to write a model binder to fix the situation.