# Why the code shown below does not render as hyperlink with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create("<a href=""" + blogComment .UserBlogUrl + """>" +  blogComment .UserBlogUrl + "</a>" )
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you not doing:

```
<a href="@blogComment.UserBlogUrl">@blogComment.UserBlogUrl</a>
```

Instead?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of .net are you on? Is it .Net 4.0. Have you considered using 
[Html.ActionLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method)