# How in asp.net mvc create link that refer to some model.property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, hyperlink, href

I have strong-type view, I want to create link that refers to Model, which is strong-typed with that view, some property (e.g Model.property).
How can I do that?
I use net4.0.
when I write ">   it do nothing.
Even visual studio don't recognize it when I write < a href="<%:   and click ctrl+space it doesn't bring anything.
This is my view

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<UrlParser.Models.Parse>" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Show</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Title: </h1>
    <%: Model.title %>
    <br />
    <h1> Description: </h1>
    <%: Model.description %>
    <% if(!Model.video.Equals("")) { %>
    <h2> Video:</h2>
    <%: Model.video %>
    <a href="<%: Model.video %>"> </a>
    <% } %>

</body>
</html>
```

I want my link refer to Model.video.

These is my controler:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using UrlParser.Models;

namespace UrlParser.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(GetUrl getUrl)
        {
           // int i = 0;
            Parse prs = new Parse(getUrl.url);
            return View("Show", prs);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you want to use a model property within a link. Follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method)

Comment: Your view should be expecting a certain model. You should have access to the properties of that model. I think you might have to post some code for us to see what you're having an issue with.

Comment: @Odnxe : I edit my question< please look.

Comment: Could you post your entire view?

Comment: @alun: Yes, you are right. <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<UrlParser.Models.Parse>" %> this was mising.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think that view will be strongly typed. You should add your strong type to the page directive. Something like Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyApp.Models.SomeModel>"

Comment: and don't thing about: <% if(!Model.video.Equals("")) { %>
 this condition is 100% true, and but link doesn't seen on the screen.

Comment: @alun: No it's strong-typed< I crate it with right-click and choose stronge-type, and when I write <%: Model.video %> it is visible, but link is invisible.

Comment: @alun: yes, and "System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<UrlParser.Models.Parse>"  , where Parse is my Model.

Comment: Try the link without the if-statement

Comment: So... My suggestion is to now show your controller that renders the view b/c your view looks correct.

Comment: @Odnxe, I add Controler code, it must be correct too. If you need I can show my Model, too.

Comment: Now it works, my mistake was that I didn't write anything at the a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure i follow you 100% but it looks like you might have your view defined without your model like:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

And you will need something like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyViewModel>" %>
```

The key above is the **MyViewModel** which is you view model.  This should have all your properties; *MyViewModel.Video*.

---

The following link was just missing the link text.

```
    <a href="<%: Model.video %>"> </a>
```

when you added something in between the  and the  it made the link visible.

Comment: I don't think it is the problem, because when I write <%: Model.video> %> it works and display what I want.

Comment: i see your updated code now... i'm not sure why that wouldnt work.  what do you get when you run that page?  do you end up with the literal "<%: Model.video %>" as the href?

Comment: No, when I write <%: Model.video %> is was shown as simple text, and when I write <a href="<%: Model.video %>"> </a>
 it doesn't show anything.

Comment: anything in the view source?  make sure you have some text for the link... like: <a href="<%: Model.video %>"><%: Model.title %> </a>   you might just be seeing a link with no text?

Comment: OO, thanks! Now it works, when i added <%: Model.title %>  it works.