# Problem with @Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with this ActionLink?

```
@Html.ActionLink(posts.Title, "PostDetails", "Blogs", new { id = posts.PostID } )
```

I am expecting this link to go to:

> http://localhost/Blogs/PostDetails?whateverpassed

But instead I see the following in Firefox:

> http://localhost:1815/Home/PostDetails?Length=5

It's not even going to Blogs controller.

Comment: What do your routing rules look like?

Comment: i am using the default one... i dont think so its goona need new routs ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are calling the right overloaded method.
If you miss one param it gives a different meaning.

[HTML.ActionLink method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505040.aspx

Please double check if you are missing a param.

Comment: well, that link sorted out everything... i have to provide the last parameter in ActionLink...

@Html.ActionLink(posts.Title, "PostDetails", "Blogs", new { id = posts.PostID }, null )

Comment: I often make this same mistake. Your original code is using `routeValues = "Blogs",  htmlAttributes = new {id = posts.PostId} `because it's the wrong overload.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the way the route values are passed, use this instead:

```
 @Html.ActionLink(posts.Title, "PostDetails", new {Controller="Blogs", id = posts.PostID } )
```

Comment: This is still wrong... It should be `new {Controller="Blogs",  id=posts.PostId} `