# ActionLink not outputting correct path

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink

Could you please help me figure out what is wrong with below razor syntax. I am trying to output an anchor tag with a link to MVC action.

Razor Syntax:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Reports List", "Index", "Reports")
```

Output in the browser:

```
<a href="/">Back to Reports List</a>
```

and not:

```
<a href="/Reports/Index">Back to Reports List</a>
```

Any idea?

Comment: have you seen that ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439375/having-a-problem-outputting-the-correct-url-from-an-actionlink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please show your route config. The url generated based on that.
It is possible that your route config start with:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Reports", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. Spot on - that was the problem. I didn't know ActionLink    checks the route config to output the paths! many thanks