# how do i get rid of blank window opening on click of actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html, razor

A new blank browserwindow opens on click of the below link created by statement below

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.InvoiceNumber, "SendPdfStatement", "Invoice", new { item.InvoiceNumber }, new { target = "_blank" })
```

I have tried with

`@Html.ActionLink(item.InvoiceNumber, "SendPdfStatement", "Invoice", new { item.InvoiceNumber }, new { target = "_self" })` which makes original window blank

`@Html.ActionLink(item.InvoiceNumber, "SendPdfStatement", "Invoice", new { item.InvoiceNumber }, null)` this also makes original window blank

`@Html.ActionLink(item.InvoiceNumber, "SendPdfStatement", "Invoice", new { item.InvoiceNumber }` raises exception in invoked method as tem.InvoiceNumber is taken as the html parameter

Please suggest

public void SendPdfStatement(string InvoiceNumber)

{

```
        InvoiceNumber = InvoiceNumber.Trim();

        ObjectParameter[] parameters = new ObjectParameter[1];
        parameters[0] = new ObjectParameter("InvoiceNumber", InvoiceNumber);

        List<Models.Statement> list = new List<Models.Statement>();
        list = _db.ExecuteFunction<Models.Statement>("uspInvoiceStatement", parameters).ToList<Models.Statement>();

        var statementResult = _db.ExecuteFunction<Models.Statement>("uspInvoiceStatement", parameters);
        Models.Statement statement = statementResult.SingleOrDefault();

        pdfStatementController.WriteInTemplate(statement);

    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify you question? Are you asking why is the new window blank?

Comment: does your SendPdfStatement action on the Invoice Controller return anything?

Comment: you just asked this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495404/new-window-opens-on-click-of-actionlink/8495638#8495638

Comment: my method does not return anything. I simply want to invoke a method without opening a new window and also my original window(with the link) should remain as it is

Comment: You need an Ajax function then. The page will not reload and your function will be executed, but you still need to return the View.

Comment: can you tell me the ajax function which can be used here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a blank window because your controllers signature is

`public void SendPdfStatement(string InvoiceNumber) { .. }` - which practically returns a void to your view.

If you do want to return something, turn your controller into `public ActionResult SendPdfStatement(...)` or even just string.. whatever you want to return.

If you do not want to return anything use [@Ajax.Actionlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink.aspx) to call that method instead.