# asp.net mvc Html.ActionLink ignoring jquery attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I have a visualization problem with a simple button, this renders perfectly

```
@Html.ActionLink("<", "Monthly", "Agenda", null, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-role", "button" }, { "data-theme", "c" }, { "data-mini", "true" } })
```

the action I'm calling though need parameters, therefore I changed it in

```
@Html.ActionLink("<", "Monthly", "Agenda", new { shift = -1 }, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-role", "button" }, { "data-theme", "c" }, { "data-mini", "true" } })
```

following this answer [HTML.ActionLink method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method)

When I change it as above the button does it's jobs but it doesn't render as a jquery mobile button anymore

it goes from this http://i47.tinypic.com/alhs9h.png

to this http://i48.tinypic.com/351ft5z.png

Thank you for helping me out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To hit the correct `Html.ActionLink` overload you need to pass the RouteValues as a `RouteValueDictionary` (not an anonymous object):

```
@Html.ActionLink("<", "Monthly", "Agenda", 
                 new RouteValueDictionary() { { "shift", -1 } }, 
                 new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-role", "button" }, { "data-theme", "c" }, { "data-mini", "true" } })
```

Alternatively, shorter / easier to read, you can pass *both* the RouteValues and the HtmlAttributes as anonymous objects:

```
@Html.ActionLink("<", "Monthly", "Agenda", new { shift = -1 }, new { data_role = "button", data_theme = "c", data_mini = "true" })
```

In the anonymous object version you have to use `data_` instead of `data-`, but the helper substitutes `_` with `-` before displaying the attribute keys so the output is the same.

Comment: +1 for the data_ pointer.  Was getting rather upset with Intellisense