# How do I generate an action link from a model class?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, html.actionlink, datatables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML.ActionLink method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method)

In my ASP.NET MVC 3 application, I wish to generate an action link from within a model class, corresponding to calling [Html.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx) in a view. The reason is I need to return links via JSON to [DataTables](http://datatables.net), to have them rendered in table cells. How should I do this?

Specifically, the model class contains a property that returns a string containing links into my application. DataTables receives JSON representations of instances of the model class, and uses this particular property to fill in table cells.

Comment: Do you want to create MyModelClass.GetLinkMethod?

Comment: @AleksejVasinov Isn't that just an implementation detail? I want to JSON-serialize a property of the class as a string containing action links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would avoid having the model generate its own links, but have the controller create the links and set the property with the resulting values. Anyways, you can create and consume UrlHelper in a controller like this:

```
var url = new UrlHelper(ControllerContext.RequestContext);
url.Action(...);
```

If you don't have access to controller context (like you decide to do this within your model separately from the view or controller), you can use

```
UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
```

Comment: This works very well excepting the rendering of the HTML link itself. That part I can easily do myself though, thanks.