# Concatenate string in Asp Mvc

Tags: string, concatenation

I am using ajax jquery for return a string , i have a entangle  , it is Concatenate string
I want concatenate :

```
string str = "";
str += "<td>"+"<%= Html.ActionLink('Edit', 'ProcessUpdate/' + s.ProductId, 'Stationery')%>"+" </td>";
```

but when i run application , this is result :

I want to run the program the following results

Edit

thank for all !

Answer (score 0):

It looks your issue is the parameters you are passing to `Html.ActionLink()`. Your question has been answered 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method). The "/" character in your second parameter is not valid since this parameter is the action name in MVC2+ or the controller name in MVC1.

Assuming `Stationery` is the controller and `ProcessUpdate` is the action on the controller, your code should look like this:

```
Html.ActionLink("Edit", "ProcessUpdate", "Stationery" new { Id = s.ProductId }, new { } )
```

And here is the signature for the action

```
public ActionResult ProcessUpdate(string id)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Note the last parameter is for Html Attributes and is required for this overload of `Html.ActionLink()` to work properly.