# Hide content in MVC page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to MVC and razor. I have an MVC 4 application. In the Shared -> _Layout.cshtml page, I have some content that I would like to hide if the user in not in the allowed list. How should I proceed?

I tried using something like this, but when I look at the running code, the parts between the <% %> are commented out.

```
<div>
    <a href="../Home/Index" style="color: White;">Home</a>
    <% if(*a condition*) { %>
        <a href="../Admin/Index" style="color: White;">Admin</a>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using razor, you just need to use `@`:

```
<div>
    <a href="../Home/Index" style="color: White;">Home</a>
    @if(1==2) {
        <a href="../Admin/Index" style="color: White;">Admin</a>
    }
</div>
```

However, I would suggest you also look at using [ActionLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method), instead of hard coding the controller routes

Comment: Thank you very much, the @ solved it. Indeed, ActionLink would be more appropriate. I have to rember to keep to razor, I used to be html and .net.

Comment: @user1482939 razor is a lovely, flowing syntax which allows you to bash out screens very quickly.