# Database access in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I am not very much familiar with `razor` view engine. I tried this code.

```
@for(var item in ViewBag.list)
{
    @foreach (var itemvote in ViewBag.listVote)
    {
        <h1>@Html.ActionLink(@item.Title, "Details", "Report", new { id = item.Id},null)</h1>
    }
}
```

> And it shows the following error:

Compiler Error Message: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has no applicable        method named 'ActionLink' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

my controller class is `ReportController` and method is `Details` to which it will be submitted.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            Report report = Context.Reports.Find(id);
            if (report == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.report = report;

            return View();
        }
```

I googled and found some link like [HTML.ActionLink method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method)

but i am still unable to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 problems with your call to actionlink.

First, the first parameter does not require a '@' because you're already using one at the start of the line with @Html.ActionLink.

Secondly, the first parameter should be `itemvote.Title` not item.Title, as you don't have a variable called `item`.

That could be part of your problem, because the compiler might not realize that @item.Title is supposed to be a string, and there is a valid signature of `ActionLink(string, string, string, Object, Object)`

Comment: i solved that problem and
<h1>@Html.ActionLink((string)@item.Title, "Details", new { id = item.Id})</h1>
this line is my answer..