# ActionLink not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm passing empid and I want it to be shown in url but it shows like querystring:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink(key.Value, "Attendance","HOD",  new {empid=key.Key}, null) 
                                                                           </li>
```

The link I want to display is like:

```
 /HOD/Attendance/xyz%2Fabc
```

but it shows me like this:

```
/HOD/Attendance?empid=xyz%2Fabc //it's like query string but i don't want that.
```

Can somebody please help? I appreciate any little help. Thanks a lot in advance.

I've this RouteMap added to Global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute (
     "HOD_AttByEmpID", // Route name
     "{controller}/{action}/{empid}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", 
                                    empid = UrlParameter.Optional }             
);
```

Comment: It should work, only when we supply values for properties that do not correspond with segment variables, the values are
appended to the outgoing URL as the query string. So i guess something is wrong with the routes. If it's working with Anuraj's example, then you misspelled the property name.

Comment: @FlaviaObreja : it's not working with anuraj's example, any more suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried like this?

```
@Html.ActionLink(key.Value, "Attendance","HOD",  new { key.Key},null)
```

Source : [HTML.ActionLink method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method)

Comment: thanks for your reply but it didn't work, returns link like:
   **"/HOD/Attendance?Key=xyz%2Fabc"**

Comment: I tried the following - @Html.ActionLink("Hello World", "ShowDetails", new { id = "1" }, null) and it is returning something like - http://localhost:50446/Home/ShowDetails/1 and this is my route config - routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: thanks a lot, I was not putting my attention towards my routeMap comfig. I had two routeMaps added with same parameters. Thanks for sharing the routeMap config.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that is because your value contains a '/'

Maybe you can try :

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink(key.Value, "Attendance","HOD",
         new {empid=Server.UrlEncode(key.Key)}, null) 
</li>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply... tried it but didn't work. Gives me the link like:
     **"/HOD/Attendance?empid=xyz%252fabc"**

Comment: @Sunny thx for the follow-up. For what it is worth, another option is to define your route url as "{controller}/{action}/{*empid}" the star would then grasp the /