# Subdomain shows full relative path from main domain on shared hosting, How to correct it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

In GoDaddy shared windows hosting, Any domain/subdomain I hosted on Subfolders, shows complete Relative Path in browser address bar.
Can any one suggest a workaround/fix for this issue.

e.g. Go to us.justcustomercare.com, notice any link in this page shows full relative path `/us.justcustomercare.com/domains/us.justcustomercare.com/`

I am using **Razor**, **LinkExtensions.ActionLink** to create the html anchors in Asp.net MVC4.

Comment: How are you generating the links? Notice that "Contact Us" does not have the extra parts: http://us.justcustomercare.com/Home/Contact

Comment: @QuetiM.Porta, thanks for the update.... If I use plain HTML for creating link like this <a href="/Home/Contact">Contact Us</a>, it works fine. However, if I use LinkExtensions.ActionLink, it resolves to complete relative path.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) LinkExtensions.ActionLink Method

> Returns an anchor element (a element) that contains the **virtual path**
>   of the specified action.

Instead, use `@Html.ActionLink()`

Comment: As I understand Html.Action can not be used as a hyperlink, it is used to get html from an MVC action.
Can you help me to understand, how should I replace LinkExtension.ActionLink with this?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `ActionLink`. Not `Action`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: But this is same as LinkExtension.ActionLink as mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method

 :(

Comment: Please explain how to use @Html.ActionLink()?