# Can't create link to other controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I using mvc3 and i have two controllers Qualification and Teacher.I'm render teacher view and from teacher view i need to go to Qualification index view page.

```
@HTML.Action-Link (model-Item => item.Qualification.Type,"../Qualification")
```

But this give error saying "cannot convert lambda expression to string".How can i fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write like this,

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "ActionName", "Controller", new { Id = parameter }, new { @class = "hide" })
```

see this link : [HTML.ActionLink method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method)