# ActionLink not working as expected in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My html code is as follows

```
<ul>
    @foreach (Department department in @Model)
    {
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink(department.Name, "Index", "Employee", new { id = department.DeptId }, null)
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

After this when i hover on the link rendered on browser it shows `http://localhost/demo/department/index`
but when i change the **index** to **Details** in the actionLink parameter , then when i hover the link it shows `http://localhost/demo/Employee/Details?id=2`

Why in the first case instead of this `http://localhost/demo/Employee/Index?id=2` , `http://localhost/demo/department/index` is coming.

I am very new to mvc. Please bear if this question is silly.
Please help me.

**UPDATE**

My route file is

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{name}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "GetCountries",
            url: "{controller}/GetCountries",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetCountries" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "GetEmployeeDetailsOnId",
            url: "Employee/Details",
            defaults: new { controller = "Employee", action = "Details" }
        );


    }
```

**Solution**

```
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "GetEmployeeDetails",
               url: "Employee/Index/{deptId}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Employee", action = "Index", deptId = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
```

Added this in route and its working.

Comment: How does your routing look like?

Comment: Does you Employee controller actually have a action called Index?

Comment: Yes it has action called Index

Comment: please check this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method

Answer (score 1):

In the first case your parameters to `ActionLink` are

```
ActionName = "Details"
ControllerName = "Employee"
```

In the second case your parameters to `ActionLink` are

```
ActionName = "Index"
ControllerName = "Employee"
```

These parameters are then matched against your routes one by one.

---

In the first case there is a match against your third route (`url: "Employee/Details"`)

In the second case there is a match against your first route (`url: "{controller}/{action}/{name}/{id}"`)

---

For more information about how parameters are matched against routes, please see the link provided by @renjith in the comments: [HTML.ActionLink method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method)