# MVC Calling a function from a partial view is not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

This is my first MVC application, and this must be something simple but I've been trying to make this work for so many hours now..

## What I want to do

I want to display a table in a partial view and be able to delete items from the parent view. The simple version looks something like this (the actual application is not about fruits):

[image]

## What I have now

### Partial View (_FruitList.cshtml)

```
<div id="listOfFruits">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th class="active">Description</th>
            <th class="active">Amount</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach(var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Description</td>
                <td>@item.Amount</td>
                <td><button class=".." onclick="d(@item.FruitID)">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

### Parent View (Home.cshtml)

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (){
            function d(id){
                var url = "/Fruit/DeleteFruit/";
                $.post(url, {id: id})
                .done(function(response){
                    $("#listOfFruits").html(response);
                });
            }
        });



    </script>
}

@{Html.RenderPartial("_FruitList", Model.FruitList);}
```

### Controller (FruitController.cs)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteFruit(int id)
{
    //Delete the selected fruit
    FruitViewMode item = new FruitViewMode();

    return PartialView(item.FruitList);
}
```

## My Question

I can view the table with the fruit data in the parent view, but clicking the `Delete` button does not call the d function in the parent view. 
(Javascript and JQuery should be working in the partial view because I've tested `alert` and `addClass` and they work fine)

I'm very new to this so it's very likely that I'm missing some basic stuff but what am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`d()` isn't declared in the global page scope, so it isn't found. declare it in the root of the `<script>` tag (i.e., not within a `document.ready`) to have access to it from the `onclick`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function d(id){
        var url = "/Fruit/DeleteFruit/";
        $.post(url, {id: id})
        .done(function(response){
            $("#listOfFruits").html(response);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Ah! It totally makes sense and it worked! Thank you!!

Comment: sure thing! make sure to mark the question as an answer so future viewers will know this answered your question if they have the same problem

Comment: Yes definitely. Actually I'm trying to but it doesn't let me do so because it's within 10 minutes after the question is posted. Thanks again for the quick answer:-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe in the past I had used a HTML.**ActionLink** for the same goal of deleting something by Id:

[HTML.ActionLink method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method)