# ASP.Net Using @Html.ActionLink() for Navbar buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on Visual Studio MVC currently. As MVC helps to create codes automatically for some functions. I am trying to understand what does this sentence of code means. I understand the first two parameters, but not the third one.

**-----> @Html.ActionLink("Text Displayed", "Method name in controller", "Third???")**

My code for my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MP.Controllers
   {
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the code I do not understand:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method read this post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3rd parameter is the name of the controller. In your case you have a controller named `HomeController` so the 3rd parameter is `"Home"` (by convention, you omit the "Controller" suffix).

In the case where the page the `@Html.ActionLink()` method is used has been generated by a method in `HomeController`, you can omit the 3rd parameter, for example, in your `About` page, you can use

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index")</li>
```

however if the `Index()` method was in (say) `ProductController`, then it would need to be

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Product")</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could see there in your intellisense system -

[image]

It is clearly mentioned here- `string controllerName`.

Moreover, There are sever 10 types of extensions you can get with this helper.