# How To Call Action in MVC from Action link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

This is My Action link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Signup", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "call-to-action", id = "registerLink" })</li>
```

And this Is My Action

```
[ActionName("Signup")]
public ActionResult Register() 
{
  return view()
}
```

Comment: Please improve your question... and write the question itself! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method - go to this question

Answer (score 0):

**In View**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Signup", "Account", null, new { @class = "call-to-action", id = "registerLink" })
```

**Controller**

```
  [ActionName("Signup")]
    public ActionResult Register() 
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: it shows Signup.cshtml , Signup.aspx , Signup.ascx no file is found

Comment: in `return view()` you have to provide View path or create corresponding view for this action method

Answer (score 0):

Why are you putting an `ActionName` data annotation over the actual action?

In order to get this to work, all you need to do is:

**HTML:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "call-to-action", id = "registerLink" })</li>
```

**Controller:**

```
//no need for data annotation
public ActionResult Register() 
{
    return View();
}
```

Let me know if this helps.