# How to pass Parameter from gridview to controller using SetDataItemTemplateContent in mvc4 devExpress by clicking Edit Button?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, gridview, devexpress

Hi i have one registration page and it contain fields called UID,UserName,Password. I am using dev Express gridview. When i click the edit button it need to pass the particular row key value to controller but it passing null parameter to controller. Now what i want is i want to pass the particular row key Parameter to controller by clicking edit button in grid view in mvc dev express gridview  using SetDataItemTemplateContent.Below i post my code please any one correct my code and tell me what mistake i did.

**My Model (UserMasterViewModel)**

```
 public int UID{get;set;}
 public string UserName{get;set;}
 public string Password{get;set;}
```

**My Controller Code**

```
Public ActionResult UserMasterEdit(int? id)
{
 View_MUsrRegistration  userregistrartion = db.MUsrRegistration.Find(id)
 UserMasterViewModel usermasterviewmodel = new UserMasterViewModel();

  usermasterviewmodel.UserName = userregistrartion.UserName;
  usermasterviewmodel.Password = userregistrartion.Password; 
  return View(usermasterviewmodel)
}
```

**Grid View Code**

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(
  settings =>
   {
    settings.Name = "gvEditing";
    settings.KeyFieldName = "UID";
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "UserMaster", Action = "UserMasterPartial" };
    settings.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);

    settings.Columns.Add(column => {
        column.Caption = "#";
        column.SetDataItemTemplateContent(c =>
        {
            ViewContext.Writer.Write(
                Html.ActionLink("Edit", "UserMasterEdit", new { UID = DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "UID") }) + "&nbsp;" +
                Html.ActionLink("Delete", "UserMasterDelete", new { ProductID = DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "UID") },
                    new { onclick = "return confirm('Do you really want to delete this record?')" })
            );
        });

        column.Settings.AllowDragDrop = DefaultBoolean.False;
        column.Settings.AllowSort = DefaultBoolean.False;
        column.Width = 70;
    });
    settings.Columns.Add("UserName");
    settings.Columns.Add("Password");
    settings.ClientLayout = (s, e) =>
    {
        if(e.LayoutMode == ClientLayoutMode.Loading) {
            if(Session["GridState"] != null)
                e.LayoutData = (string)Session["GridState"];
        }
        else
            Session["GridState"] = e.LayoutData;
    };
}).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

**EDIT View**

```
@model MSSERP.Models.UserMasterViewModel
 @{
  Html.EnableClientValidation(); 
}

 @using(Html.BeginForm("UserMaterUpdate", "UserMaster", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "edit_form" })) {
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.UID)
<div class="line">
   @Html.Label(UserNmae)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.UserName)
</div>

<div class="line">
   @Html.Label(Password)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Password)
</div>
<div class ="line">
<input type="submit" value ="Save"/>
</div>
```

In this i am clicking edit button it passing the null value to controller. I tried many ways but cant able to pass the UID parameter to controller.
i donno what mistake i did in this action. I tried my level best to explain this issue Any one understand and help  me to resolve this issue.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following'

Change:

```
Html.ActionLink("Edit", "UserMasterEdit", new { UID = DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "UID") })
```

To:

```
Html.ActionLink("Edit", "UserMasterEdit", new { id = DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "UID") }, null)
```

The parameter name should match the controller's parameter name.
The added null argument is needed to ensure that the right parsing method is called.  see this link:[HTML.ActionLink method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method)

Comment: This is not bad. But I will post an easier answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the GridView where your DisplayFor's are located:

```
<a class="ml-2" href="/Merchant/Merchant_Boarding/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GUID)" title="Edit">Edit</a>
```

Or use an ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Merchant_Boarding", new { id = (item.GUID) }, new { @class = "ml-2" })
```

In your Get:

```
        [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Merchant_Boarding(string? id)
    {
        var model = new MerchantDetail();
        MerchantData merchdata = new MerchantData();

        model = merchdata.RetrieveMerchantData(id);
        merchdata.Dispose();
        return View(model);
    }
```

The id variable will contain the value you passed in from the grid view. From there, you can populate your model and show it.