# MVC C# Pass parameter to VIA ActionLink to Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

### Issue

---

I have a link on my Register page which needs to call a method in the Controller that sends out a code. When the user finishes the form they click submit and you can check the codes match and register the user.

The problem I am having is when the user clicks the Send Code link, I need to pass the email that has been entered as a parameter which i can't seem to do.

### Code

---

Here is how my ActionLink is setup:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Send verification code", "Verify", new { id = "codeLink" })%>
```

This ActionLink makes a Javascript AJAX call to the method in the Controller to stop the page refreshing. *The variable 'email' is populated as i have debugged and tested this.*

```
    $("#codeLink").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var dataToPost = "{ email:'" + email + "'}";

        $.ajax({

            url: $(this).attr("href"),
            data: dataToPost,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/jsonrequest; charset=utf-8"
        });
    });
```

The way the email box is setup is like below:

```
        <p>
            <%:Html.Label(Resources.UserEmailAddress)%>
            <%:Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.uEmail, new { id = "uEmail" }) %>
            <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.uEmail) %>
        </p>
```

These steps successfully call the method on the controller but the parameter (*JSON*) does not get passed.

```
    public void Verify(string email)
    {
        var VerificationCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        VerificationCode = VerificationCode.Substring(VerificationCode.IndexOf("-") + 1, 4);

        Session["VerificationCode"] = VerificationCode;

        var emailUsername = new EmailValidationCode();
        emailUsername.SendEmail(email, VerificationCode);
    }
```

So I need a way of the user clicking "Send Code" which stays on the same page and calls the Verify method in the controller, passing the email that has been entered above it.

Comment: I assume you have a typo in your `ActionLink()` - your using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object%29) which adds a route value, not a html attribute (your not generating an element with `<a id="codeLink" ...>`

Comment: If its not a typo, then your just making a normal redirect and not sending anything for the `email` parameter

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry I am unsure what you mean. Could you explain and show me.

Comment: You should use simple `<a id="codeLink">Click</a>`. @StephenMuecke explains better above,

Comment: It needs to be `Html.ActionLink("Send verification code", "Verify", null, new { id = "codeLink" })` in order to add `id="codeLink"` in the `<a>` tag

Comment: @StephenMuecke is right, check this for furhter info : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method

Comment: @BenClarke, also, you should look at my answer, because you have to use `JSON.stringify()` in order to send a json `object`.

Comment: Please do not save the verification code in session because mostly verification links are valid for a day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass a javascript `object`.

```
var dataToPost = { email:email};
$.ajax({

        url: $(this).attr("href"),
        data: dataToPost,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false
 });
```

Also, `contentType` is the type of data you're sending, so `application/json`; The default is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8.

If you use `application/json`, you have to use `JSON.stringify()` in order to send JSON `object`.

`JSON.stringify()` turns a javascript object to json text and stores it in a string.

```
var dataToPost = { email:email};
$.ajax({

        url: $(this).attr("href"),
        data: JSON.stringify(dataToPost),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
 });
```

Comment: Thanks. If he use `application/jsonrequest; charset=utf-8` he have to `stringify` the javascript object, using JSON.stringify.

Comment: This did not work. What parameter should the 'Verify' method accept? A String or an Object?

Comment: Have you removed `application/jsonrequest; charset=utf-8` ?

Comment: Yes i removed that bit.

Comment: @BenClarke , have a look at my answer.

Comment: great explaination for default behavior

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Finally got it working. It was a mix between your answer and Stephen Muecke comment. Thanks for your help!