# Class is not applying for Link

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Here i am using anchor tag for this class is not applying.And this is my code

```
 <td> <a href="@Url.Action("ViewServiceDetails", "ServiceConsumer", new { BookingID = CAH.BookingID, @class = "btn btn-link", data_toggle = "modal", data_target = "#ViewServiceDetails" })">@CAH.BookingID</a></td>
```

Previously i used

```
<td> @Html.ActionLink((string)CAH.BookingID, "ViewServiceDetails", "ServiceConsumer", new { BookingID = CAH.BookingID }, new { @class = "btn btn-link", data_toggle = "modal", data_target = "#ViewServiceDetails" })</td>
```

but iam getting error for second one

Comment: Use `Html.ActionLink`

Comment: "for this class is not applying" what class? what are you asking?!

Comment: @Alex class which i created for desing i.e.@class = "btn btn-link"

Comment: Why do you put the class inside of the @Url.action? Wh don't you put btn btn-link inside the anchor tag directly? inside of the new { .. } there should be params, not anchor details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about this wrong.
You're getting mixed up with 'normal' HTML, and helpers.

You don't pass in your @class attributes to the anonymous object passed to Url.Action

Just use normal HTML in conjunction with `Url.Action` if you want:
You're going about this wrong.
You're getting mixed up with 'normal' HTML, and helpers.

You don't pass in your @class attributes to the anonymous object passed to Url.Action

Just use normal HTML in conjunction with `Url.Action` if you want:

```
 <td> 
     <a href="@Url.Action("ViewServiceDetails", "ServiceConsumer", new { BookingID = CAH.BookingID })" 
        class="btn btn-link" 
        data-toggle="modal" 
        data-target="#ViewServiceDetails">
        @CAH.BookingID       
     </a>
 </td>
```

You could use `Html.ActionLink` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method)

```
@Html.ActionLink(CAH.BookingID,  // <-- Text of link.
                "ServiceConsumer",  // <-- Controller Name.
                "ViewServiceDetails",   // <-- ActionMethod
                new { BookingID = CAH.BookingID }, // <-- Route arguments.
                new { @class="btn btn-link", data_toggle = "modal", data_target = "#ViewServiceDetails" }  // <-- htmlArguments
                )
```

Comment: are you sure you copy/pasted correctly - there's a space in your url you posted above  (%20ViewServiceDetails)