# View returns null to controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using razor view to display the info and the info display perfectly but when I press the action link to download the file the action comes null from the view.

View:

```
@model Innovation_Internship.Models.Applicant

@Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", "Admin", new { filename = Model.Resume })
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Download(string filename) <-- comes null
    {
        try
        {

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //download failed 
            //handle exception
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You were able to see it come back over the wire as null, have you checked to make sure it is not going out as null?

Comment: @RossBush filename has the value but when I press the link in the controller comes null.

Comment: Can you post the body and/or url of your trace when you press download in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model.Resume seems to be an object rather than as string.
Maybe the object or refrence is null. - maybe use .ToString()

Also add null to the end or you may call the wrong version of the function

```
@Html.ActionLink("Text","Action","Controller", new { item.ID }, null)
```

There is also another SO post related:
[HTML.ActionLink method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method)