# ASP.NET MVC Routing in IIS with application name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and when I tried to host my working application into IIS, the routing fails as I now requires the application name in front of my controller name.

Eg. my default page navigates using:

```
localhost/ControllerName/Index
```

However after hosting:

```
ipaddress/ApplicationName/ControllerName/Index
```

It now requires the `ApplicationName` before my controller.

I tried adding an additional MapRoute:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ApplicationName",
            url: "ApplicationName/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

However it still navigates to the defaults.

How do I have the routing table skip the application name?

Comment: I think (might be wrong though) that this is because your IIS can host multiple applications, so `ipaddress/ApplicationName` is so the IIS server knows which application you want to route to and has nothing to do with your actual application

Comment: @MindSwipe Yes, it host multiple applications right now, will I have to manually change all the url?

Comment: No. If you change the routing (like you did in your example) the URL of the application will be `ipaddress/ApplicationName/ApplicationName/`. The `ipaddress/ApplicationName` routing scheme shouldn't be a problem, as long as you are generating your links (`<a>foo</a>` tags) and not hardcoding them. You can use [@Hmtl.ActionLink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201341/9363973) to dynamically generate them