# Is it possible to include the application name in the asp.net core routes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a simple phonebook app that allows the user to search for an employee via a dropdown list of departments or by name via text input. The way I'm handling the search is simply changing the action attribute of the html form with javascript based on whatever they typed or whichever option they selected in the dropdown:

```
function selectedOption(option) {
    var selValue = option.value;

    document.getElementById("search-form").action = "/home/index/" + selValue;
}
```

This works on localhost but when I host it on IIS:

```
machineName/appName
```

becomes

```
machineName/home/index/selValue
```

cutting off the app name and returning a 404 error

The only way I've been able to get around this is with some hardcoding to check whether "home/index" exists in the path already...

```
function selectedOption(option) {
    var selValue = option.value;

    if (window.location.href.includes("home")) {
        var searchDest = selValue
    } else {
        var searchDest = window.location.href + "/home/index/" + selValue
    }

    document.getElementById("search-form").action = searchDest;
}
```

This works but it is not very clean or conventional. Is there some way I can have the app name configured in Startup.cs? I saw the same issue in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57352760/asp-net-mvc-routing-in-iis-with-application-name) but I'm getting syntax errors when I try to add another MapRoute. This is all that I currently have:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
     routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: Try excluding the leading slash, ie "home/index/"

Comment: I tried that already and it works the same way but in reverse. The first search works and subsequent searches do not as every search appends a new "home/index" to the end of the existing url

Comment: you can try ```document.getElementById("search-form").action = '<%= Url.Content("~/") %>' + "/home/index/" + selValue;```. `Url.Content` will generate a url relative to your application. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922997/asp-net-mvc-resolve-urls-in-javascript/923024

Comment: I might be wrong but that looks like erb syntax. I'm in a cshtml file so that doesn't work. Anyway, I could do the same thing with window.location.href but I want to avoid coding like that because I don't think it's best practice. Thanks for the contribution though!

Comment: For cshtml, you can try `@Url.Content("~/home/index/")`

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned above by `@Desmond Chin`, for `cshtml` you can use `HTML` helpers. I think the best one for that case is to use `@Url.Action(actionName, controllerName)` instead `@Url.Content()` - which is used for `js`, `css`, `img`, etc..

You can use this code bellow to achieve this:

```
function selectedOption(option) {
    var selValue = option.value;

    document.getElementById("search-form").action = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")?<<VARIABLENAMEHERE>>'+selValue;

}
```

The Html Helper will take care of your url, virtual paths and etc