# How to pass a parameter to a controller from a cshtml view in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-routing

net MVC 4 I followed the microsoft tutorials on how to pass a parameter to a controller from a cshtml view in mvc and I keep getting an error that says the resource cannot be found.If I put a break point in the cshtml I can actually see the value of the Id but it is not hitting the controller at all seems like it cant find it

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following
>   URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /UploadLogs/DisplayUploadedFileContents/89

This is my controller method

```
public class DisplayUploadedFileController : Controller
{
    private MarketingDBEntitiesModel db = new MarketingDBEntitiesModel();
    // GET: DisplayUploadedFile
    public ActionResult DisplayUploadedFileContents(int UploadId)
    {
        return View(db.marketingdbclients_dataTable.OrderByDescending(r => r.ClientId).Where(r => r.ClientDataId < 1000).ToList());
       // return View();.
    }
}
```

**My line in the cshtml**

```
<td>    
    @*@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.UploadId })*@

    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "DisplayUploadedFileContents", new { id = item.UploadId })    
</td>
```

**My route config**

```
 routes.MapRoute(
      name: "DisplayUploadedFileContents",
      //url: "",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "DisplayUploadedFile", action = "DisplayUploadedFileContents", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a couple of changes should get this working.

First, if you want to use the routing for the url like this `{controller}/{action}/{id}`, change the parameter name in the controller action from `UploadId` to `id`:

```
public ActionResult DisplayUploadedFileContents(int id)
```

Next, it looks like you're linking from a different controller since in the error the requested URL is `/UploadLogs/DisplayUploadedFileContents/89` (note `UploadLogs` is not `DisplayUploadedFile`).

Linking to the `DisplayUploadedFile` controller from a view that belongs to a different controller, you will need to use this overload taking 5 parameters:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Display File Contents", "DisplayUploadedFileContents", "DisplayUploadedFile", 
                     null, new { id = item.UploadId })
```

However, if you're accessing the controller from a view within the same controller you should be able to use this overload for `ActionLink` taking 3 parameters:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Display File Contents", "DisplayUploadedFileContents", new { id = item.UploadId })
```

Please refer to the ActionLink [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

Answer (score 0):

```
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

You didn't respect the routing configuration. Try:

```
@Html.ActionLink("DisplayUploadedFile", "DisplayUploadedFileContents", new { UploadId = item.UploadId })
```

Comment: Thank you @sander you are right the conventions were not followed so I have sorted them out but I still get the same error. I think something else is missing

Comment: I edited the parameter name
Also, you don't need to map the route. Just follow the default routing conventions. I think you mapping this route in the routeconfig is also interfering.

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("DisplayUploadedFile", "DisplayUploadedFileContents", new { UploadId = item.UploadId })`   That is what I have now so I am not sure what I missing here

Comment: remove the mapRoute that you write for DisplayUploadedFileContents and keep (or restore) the original routing configuration in routeconfig.cs

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ActionLink("DisplayUploadedFile", "DisplayUploadedFileContents", new { UploadId = item.UploadId}, null )
```

You need the Argument for "htmlArgument"

Please Refer to: [HTML.ActionLink method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method)